# When does console.log get executed?

Tags: javascript, class, logging, console

I'm trying to debug some pretty simple Javascript using console.log, but it's outputting values for variables that are not changed until *after* the console.log call, when the variables are 'class' members (Chrome 22, Firefox 16).

An example of what I expect to happen would be like this:

```
var a = 1;
console.log(a);
a += 20;

//console output says a is 1
```

But if the variable is a 'class' member:

```
var a = new myClass(1);
console.log(a);
a.x += 20;

//console output says a.x is 21
```

If the console does not log the value as it exists when the log is called, when does it finally decide to log the value, and how can I work around this!?

fwiw here is the entirety of the code:

```
function myClass() {
    myClass.myClass.apply(this, arguments);
    if (this.constructor === myClass) this.myClass.apply(this, arguments);
};
myClass.myClass = function () {};
myClass.prototype.myClass = function (x_) {
    if (x_ === undefined) x_ = 0;
    this.x = x_;
}

var a = new myClass(1);
console.log(a);
a.x += 20;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Immediately, but the *state of objects* is fetched when you expand the object manually in console - not at the time of the logging.

By the time you expand it in your console, the code to add 20 has executed a long time ago (in relative terms) and it says `x: 21`

Comment: That almost makes sense for Chrome where I have to expand it manually. For FF it's already expanded, with the same result... I see now a bunch of related questions to the right there which for some reason were not showing as suggestions while I was entering the question - seems like the answer is to stringify objects. I really think the name 'log' is a bad choice for this function, as a log is usually a record of past events and status. At the very least I would not have wasted an hour trying to figure out what the hell was going on. Nonetheless, problem is solved, thankyou!

Comment: In the Chome console, large objects are not fully shown by default. There  is a small triangle icon which you can click to expand the log entry and see the full details.

Comment: @iforce2d The current FF behavior is similar to Chrome as of Mar, 2019