# Array is giving an undefined in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to get the id of each button and keep it in array. but the array looks undefined. why

Jquery CODE :

```
var arr = new Array();

$(".button").each(function () {
     arr.push($(this).attr('id'));              
})

console.log(arr);//undefined

 }
```

HTML CODE :

```
    <div id="1" class="button" data-bind="dxButton: { }"></div>
    <div id="2" class="button" data-bind="dxButton: { }"></div>
    <div id="3" class="button" data-bind="dxButton: { }"></div>
    <div id="4" class="button" data-bind="dxButton: { }"></div>
```

Comment: Did you actually set `id` attribute to each element?

Comment: Your code is fine. Should work. http://jsbin.com/xepenivohu/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: are you running this after the buttons have rendered?

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: Array(4)
0
:
"1"
1
:
"2"
2
:
"3"
3
:
"4"
length
:
4

Comment: Probably you didn't put the code inside `$(document).ready()` voting to close as  a problem that can no longer be reproduced

Comment: It's likely a timing issue. Ensure that your JavaScript is being run inside of a document ready function, or in a script that is loaded at the **end** of your <body>

Comment: @RoyiNamir it is work, thank you

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, checkout my jsfiddle [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/1mbq2mn7/

You do have an extra } at the end, but I'm assuming you would have seen the error in the console log.

Comment: `$(this).prop('id')` can be just `this.id`.  Also this use case could use the `map()` method.  Edit: which @ZakariaAcharki did both in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(function(){
         var arr = new Array();
         $(".button").each(function () {
               arr.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });
        console.log(arr); //Array(4) 0:"1" 1:"2" 2:"3" 3:"4" length:4
      });



<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="1" class="button" data-bind="dxButton: { }"></div>
      <div id="2" class="button" data-bind="dxButton: { }"></div>
      <div id="3" class="button" data-bind="dxButton: { }"></div>
      <div id="4" class="button" data-bind="dxButton: { }"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

The result is:
Array(4)
0:"1"
1:"2"
2:"3"
3:"4"
length:4

Comment: Please explain why your code works, and the OP's code doesn't

Comment: On his code, there was one extra bracket }

Comment: The code must be inside Ready function, otherwise it might execute in wrong time.

Comment: I was actually meaning to the fact that your code executes after the DOM is loaded, but your answer is correct so you deserve an upvote

Answer (score 1):

Using the `map()` function is mor efficient in this case.

**NOTE :** Your code should work try just to insert it inside theready function to ensure that the button's in your DOM are fully loaded :

```
$(function(){
   //Your logic here
});
```

Hopet his helps.

```js
$(function() {
  var arr = $(".button").map(function() {
    return this.id;
  }).get();

  console.log(arr);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="1" class="button" data-bind="dxButton: { }"></div>
<div id="2" class="button" data-bind="dxButton: { }"></div>
<div id="3" class="button" data-bind="dxButton: { }"></div>
<div id="4" class="button" data-bind="dxButton: { }"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone, it worked like this.

```
var arr = [];
$(".button").each(function () {
  arr.push($(this).attr('id'));              
        })
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: There is no diff between [] and new Array (there is but at least not to your scenario).

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in your example is a bit off. You're missing a `;` and have an extra `}`.

Cleaning it up, we have:

```
var arr = new Array();
$(".button").each(function () {
  arr.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
console.log(arr);
```

Refer to working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/8Lt2m4u2/

As others have suggested, this may be a timing issue, however the `console.log(arr);` should not return `undefined` at any point, as you define it and initialize it to an empty array. Even if your buttons do not exist in the DOM at the time of the `console.log`, it should at least print an empty array.

One quirk to be aware of, is that `console.log` does not necessarily represent the value you expect. Refer to [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218273/when-does-console-log-get-executed) for details. A workaround would be doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));`, which will not matter if the object changes before you view it in the developer console. It will print what the value was at the time of executing the `console.log`.

Comment: semicolon `;` isn't required in JS code.