# Angular7: Form validation differnces

Tags: angular, forms, validation, upload

I'm facing troubles when checking the validity of a control.
When I log the **full object** is the `valid` property is `true` and when logging the `valid` **property only** it yields `false`.
Why? And how to properly check the validity of the particular form 'control'?

Here's the code in my src/app/customers/customer-edit/customer-edit.component.ts file:

```
  onDocPicked(event: Event, type: string) {
    const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    this.customerForm.get('docs').patchValue({
      [type]: file
    });
    this.customerForm.get('docs').get(type).updateValueAndValidity();
    this.customerForm.get('docs').get(type).markAsDirty();
    console.log(this.customerForm.get('docs').get(type)); // <---- HERE THE VALID PROPERTY IS TRUE (when uploading a pdf / image -- Or false when updading any other file)
    console.log(this.customerForm.get('docs').get(type).valid); // <--- AND THERE FALSE (no matter the type of file being uploaded)
  }
```

The file "picked" is first being validated by a `mimeValidator` accepting images and pdfs:

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, Observer, of } from 'rxjs';

export const mimeType = (
  control: AbstractControl
): Promise<{ [key: string]: any }> | Observable<{ [key: string]: any }> => {
  if (!control.value || typeof(control.value) === 'string') {  return of(null); }
  const file = control.value as File;
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  const frObs = Observable.create(
    (observer: Observer<{ [key: string]: any }>) => {
      fileReader.addEventListener('loadend', () => {
        const arr = new Uint8Array(fileReader.result as ArrayBuffer ).subarray(0, 4);
        let header = '';
        let isValid = false;
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          header += arr[i].toString(16);
        }
        switch (header) {
          case '89504e47':
            isValid = true;
            break;
          case 'ffd8ffe0':
          case 'ffd8ffe1':
          case 'ffd8ffe2':
          case 'ffd8ffe3':
          case 'ffd8ffe8':
            isValid = true;
            break;
          case '25504446':
            isValid = true;
            break;
          default:
            isValid = false; // Or you can use the blob.type as fallback
            break;
        }
        if (isValid) {
          observer.next(null);
        } else {
          observer.next({ invalidMimeType: true });
        }
        observer.complete();
      });
      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
  );
  return frObs;
};
```

Here's a stackblitz to my project: https://stackblitz.com/github/ardzii/test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So why does the console logs differ? We can start by saying that angular forms are in fact asynchronous, so that is part of the answer. Secondly we have to know how console log works. As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13218278/7741865):

> the state of objects is fetched when you expand the object manually in console - not at the time of the logging.

So the `valid` state has then already been set. Since forms are asynchronous, sometimes we need a slight timeout to get the most fresh value, so doing this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(this.customerForm.get('docs').get(type).valid);
},100);
```

will print `true`

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-o8qeqm?file=src/app/customers/customer-edit/customer-edit.component.ts)**

Comment: Understood. How to chain up some commands asynchronously on my form then? My objective is simple: create an alert if the mime type is incorrect and reset the corresponding portion of the form... Is there any way to create a promise on the `updateValueAndValidity()` command and chain-up the rest?